# To find all matches in list

Tags: python, list

I am trying list out all matches of an element in a list. But getting it wrong. whats wrong in below code.

```
theList = ['a','e','i','o','u','e','o','e']

def matchall1(theList, value, pos=0):
    loc = pos - 1
    try:
        loc = theList.index(value, loc+1)
        yield loc
    except ValueError:
        pass

value = 'e'
for loc in matchall1(theList, value):
    print("match at", loc+1, "position.")
```

Result i am getting from above code is just ¨match at 2 position.¨

Comment: Considering that we already have 2 deleted answers with a score of -1 that both misunderstood the problem, I think we have to ask for a [mcve].

Comment: Your function `yield`s just one time. You need to use a loop (or recursion).

Comment: You can find several solutions to your problem among the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python?rq=1

Comment: @Aran-Fey I am calling the method matchall1 in a loop, right? so it should proceed to search for the next occurrence from the loc+1 location?

Comment: @arunchakravarthy No, you're not actually calling it in a loop. You're running a loop that depends on its result. It should have a loop and generate *all* the results on its own. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

That might be as simple as that **you forgot the loop**:

```
def matchall1(theList, value, pos=0):
    loc = pos - 1
    try:
        while True:  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            loc = theList.index(value, loc+1)
            yield loc
    except ValueError:
        pass

value = 'e'
for loc in matchall1(theList, value):
    print("match at", loc+1, "position.")
```

Output:

```
match at 2 position.
match at 6 position.
match at 8 position.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find *all* matches, you'll need some form of repetition (iterative loop or recursion).

Judging by the signature of your function your intention was to use recursion, which would look like:

```
def matchall_version1(theList, value, i=0):
    try:
        i = theList.index(value, i)
        yield i
        yield from matchall_version1(theList, value, i+1)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

And using a loop your code would look like:

```
def matchall_version2(theList, value):
    i = 0
    try:
        while True:
            i = theList.index(value, i + 1)
            yield i
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

However I'd like to suggest this other version, which is far more readable than yours imho:

```
def matchall_version3(theList, value):
    for i, x in enumerate(theList):
        if x == value:
            yield i
```

All three versions yield to the same result. This:

```
theList = ['a','e','i','o','u','e','o','e']
print(list(matchall_version1(theList, 'e')))
print(list(matchall_version2(theList, 'e')))
print(list(matchall_version3(theList, 'e')))
```

Prints this:

```
[1, 5, 7]
[1, 5, 7]
[1, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by a list comprehension

```
[index for index, letter in enumerate(theList) if letter==value]
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is a bit confusing, better use a generator expression:

```
theList = ['a','e','i','o','u','e','o','e']
def matchAll(element, lst):
    yield from (i for i, e in enumerate(lst) if e == element)
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/FlusteredDeadlyDistributeddatabase)

Answer (score 0):

I won't get into the technicalities of the kind of question you ask, instead I'll give you an answer that might help you solve your problem.

```
theList = ['a','e','i','o','u','e','o','e']

def matchall1(theList, value, pos=0):
    loc = pos - 1
    try:
        for items in theList:  #ADD THIS TO YOUR CODE AND YOU'LL BE GOOD
            loc = theList.index(value, loc+1)
            yield loc
    except ValueError:
        pass

value = 'e'
for loc in matchall1(theList, value):
    print("match at", loc+1, "position.")
```

This gives you a comprehensive output, i.e one at a time. If you want all the positions in the same output statement then I'd suggest you to add it to a list and then pass it in the for loop implemented later.

**EDIT 1:**
I've quicky added the part where you can output all the positions in the same statement. The code might look nasty, and **Not-Professional**, but it works. Take a look at it

```
theList = ['a','e','i','o','u','e','o','e']

def matchall1(theList, value, pos=0):
    loc_list = []
    loc = pos - 1
    try:
        for items in theList:
            loc = theList.index(value, loc+1)
            loc_list.append(loc)
            yield loc_list
    except ValueError:
        pass

value = 'e'
for loc in matchall1(theList, value):
    continue
new_loc = []
for x in loc:
    x+=1
    new_loc.append(x)

pos = ",".join(str(x) for x in new_loc)

print("Match at", pos, "position.")
```

**Output:**

```
Match at 2,6,8 position.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
theList = ['a','e','i','o','u','e','o','e']

def matchall1(theList, value, pos=0):
    loc = pos - 1
    loc = [i for i, v in enumerate(theList) if v == value]
    for p in loc:
        yield p

value = 'e'
for loc in matchall1(theList, value):
    print("match at", loc+1, "position.")
```

Comment: What's the use of a generator if you start by building a full list ?